# How to hierarchically query PostgreSQL data coming from OpenStreetMap

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, sql, osmosis

I have loaded OpenStreetMap data into a PostgreSQL database using Osmosis. This is done by using the snapshot schema.

I filtered the data and loaded only: country & city information

```
osmosis --read-pbf planet-latest.osm.pbf --tf accept-nodes place=country,city --tf reject-relations --tf reject-ways --lp --write-pgsql host="localhost" database="testing" user="postgres" password="s5mLzcqy"
```

This data is correctly loaded, but now I want to query this data. The output of this query should be the name of the city and next to it the name of the country.

I already have this query which extracts the name of the cities:

```
SELECT 
    tags->'name' AS name    
FROM 
    nodes 
WHERE 
    tags->'place' IN ('city')
;
```

Can someone tell me how I can also get the names of the country the city is in?

**Update:**
I tried to work with the ST_Contains() function, but I can't get it to work. Is there someone that has experience in working with this function?

Comment: You have to query for all elements the city is located in and then look at their tags. Alternatively install a geocoder such as [Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim).

Answer (score 1):

You can't perform any spatial relations like ST_Contains cause you've got only nodes in your database. To do this you need also country borders as areas. You can get this from OSM (filter by boundary=administrative and admin_level=2) or other sources (e.g. http://www.naturalearthdata.com/). When you'll get it proper query will be something like this:

```
SELECT c.name as city, b.name as country
FROM nodes c
JOIN borders b on ST_Intersects(b.way, c.way)
```

Alternative way is to use an 'is_in:country' tag, but it's obsolete and many cities don't have it nowadays.